# Different layout for columns grid at md and at sm/xs - Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

guys. I have a little problem here working with bootstrap. I am trying to make a div container with a row containing 3 columns equally proportioned in width :

```
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-4" style="background:red;">logo</div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="background:blue;">content</div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="background:yellow;">content+imgs</div>

    </div>

</div>
```

The problem I have is that I want the column with 'logo' to be the second one (after 'content') on xs/sm devices or at resizing the browser window. I tried with push and pull, but I want the columns to be one above each other, not inline, as at the md devices. I have no clue how to do that, any help? :)

Comment: What you want is order classes: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#order-classes

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. Though, how can i change the order just at resizing, and display them one above each other?

Comment: You can add to the existing classes for each div another class col-sx-12, so for small screens they are only one per row.

Comment: Thanks very much. Appreciate the help, guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using order classes with bootstrap, you can change the order of the columns responsively.

This example will put the second column first on XS and SM screens.

```
<!--bootstrap 4-->
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 order-2 order-md-1">first</div>
      <div class="col-md-4 order-1 order-md-2">second</div>
      <div class="col-md-4 order-3 order-md-3">third</div>
    </div>
```

**edit:**

For bootstrap 3 (3.3.7) you will need to use push & pull classes. In your case, you would have to make the logo the second column. Mobile counts as the starting point in bootstrap development.

```
<!-- bootstrap 3 -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-4" style="background-color:red;">content</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-pull-4" style="background-color:blue;">logo</div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color:yellow;">content+imgs</div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, Jared! Do you happen to know the classes for this purpose on bootstrap 3 (3.3.7) ? :)

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if there is a possibility to not make the logo column the second one on desktop and laptop screens, just the second one on mobile devices, but I see your point. Thank you again for the help.